# ModuleNotFound error when using PIP in pycharm venv

Tags: pycharm, python-3.9, ubuntu-22.04

I keep on getting an error when trying to use pip in my virtual environment in pycharm. Every time I try and install a package using pip it comes back with a ModuleNotFoundError.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xKPW.png)

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Pycharm
Python3.9 Interpreter

Have tried from pycharm terminal and also package manager but they both have the same error.

Comment: Your `pip` executable doesn't match the Python interpreter used by PyCharm. Try with `python -m pip install <package>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As 9769953 commented, you can use:

```
python3 -m pip install <package>
```

Also you can check which pip you are using when you use command line install. (Execute below in shell)

```
which pip
```

It will give path of pip which will be used when you try **pip install < package >** and it should match same path with your python interpreter:

```
which python
```

[>> Image: Virtual environment python interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPL2E.png)

[>> Image: Default python interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gltbn.png)